# Apache2: standart rewrite rule isn't working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii

Has a fresh setup of Apache 2.2 + PHP 5.3. Trying to run Yii site, which requires *.htaccess* file to be as following:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

But instead of running *index.php* file it lists the directory.

What I know:

- *.htaccess* is being read and processed - if you break it, you get 500 IE.
- *mod_rewrite* is *On*: LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
- PHP is up, I was able to run *Adminer* w/o any issues
- Virtual Hosts file looks fine (see below)

*httpd-vhosts.conf*:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "d:/denis/www/yii.local"
ServerName yii.local

    ErrorLog "logs/yii.local-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/yii.local-access.log" common

# Other directives here

# DirectoryIndex index.php

<Directory "D:/denis/www/yii.local">    
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

    #AccessFileName htaccess

</VirtualHost>
```

**Update:** If I add *Options -Indexes* to *.htaccess* I am getting 403 Forbidden, due to "Directory index forbidden by Options directive".

Comment: Try adding 'RewriteBase /' under the `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: @arco444 Didn't help.

Comment: and it works fine if you directly navigate to `index.php`?

Comment: @arco444 nope, but it works fine if I am trying to load *yii.local/id1* or any other custom page. Issue with the / path only...

Comment: If I add *Options -Indexes* to *.htaccess* I am getting 403 Forbidden, due to "Directory index forbidden by Options directive".

Comment: Do you get a 404 navigating to index.php? What directory is your `.htaccess` in?

Comment: @arco444 *.htaccess* is in document root, not sure about 404 though (default installation)

Comment: What are the last lines of `access.log` and `error.log` files for this site when you go to `index.php`?

Comment: Add `DirectoryIndex index.php` on top of your .htaccess? Are both `.htaccess` and `index.php` placed in `d:/denis/www/yii.local` folder?

Comment: Uncomment the `DirectoryIndex` directive and let it read `DirectoryIndex index.php`